Pyspark parse out xml nodes in a string column of a dataframe
hello requesting for help
im looking to parse out certain elements in a xml string column, in a pyspark dataframe.
sample xml string in the dataframe
(This is only 1 cell in the dataframe)

<doc>
    <elem name='Countries'>
        <elem name='countryCd'>US</elem>
    </elem>
    <elem name='Addresses'>
        <elem name='Address1'>ABC G</elem>
        <elem name='Address2'>Street 10</elem>
        <elem name='State' />
        <elem name='Country'>VN</elem>
    </elem>
    <elem name='Addresses'>
        <elem name='Address1'>ABC F</elem>
        <elem name='Address2'>Street 15</elem>
        <elem name='State' />
        <elem name='Country'>UK</elem>
    </elem>
    <elem name='Ids'>
        <elem name='idType'>02</elem>
        <elem name='idNumber'>ABC234</elem>
        <elem name='idCountry' /></elem>
    <elem name='Ids'>
        <elem name='idType'>03</elem>
        <elem name='idNumber'>ABC2</elem>
        <elem name='idCountry'>AU</elem>
    </elem>
</doc>


i need to get out all the country related tags and values, in the same dataframe.
ive tried using xpath but it seems like my syntax is incorrect. seeking your help here.
Tried to search other sources but because the xml schema is different, I can’t seem to figure out the right solution
code:
import xml.tree.ElementTree as ET
parsed_df = df.selectExpr(
    "xpath_string('*', '/doc/Ids/elem[@name=\"idCountry\"]/text()') AS idCountry",
    "xpath_string('*', '/doc/Addresses/elem[@name=\"Address1\"]/text()') AS Address1",
    "xpath_string('*', '/doc/Addresses/elem[@name=\"Address2\"]/text()') AS Address2",
    "xpath_string('*', '/tdoc/Addresses/elem[@name=\"Country\"]/text()') AS Country",
    "xpath_string('*', '/doc/Countries/elem[@name=\"countryCd\"]/text()') AS countryCd"
)


Your xml is invalid. Check your xml here. https://jsonformatter.org/xml-validator
